# Why does my jar not reflect changes?

Tags: java, jar, processing

I have a spooky issue.

I have downloaded the XBee API, which comes packaged in a jar and with source. I would like to make some changes to the library, recompile it, repackage it into a jar, and use the modified library.

I have made changes to the library using NetBeans, deleted the old jar, and used NetBeans to generate a new jar. However, when I run the program, the changes that I've made do not execute (frustrated, I put a call to System.exit(0) in the constructor of the main XBee object as a sort of catchall test whether my changes work).

I have also checked the java.library.path variable and made certain that there are no other copies of the XBee jar in any of the directories.

Why does the jar not reflect my changes?? Any ideas are welcome. Thanks,
John

Comment: to test, i'd ad a System.exit as you mention, compile, and then before jaring it up, do a javap -v MyClass on the class you modified, and see if the System.exit is in there. That will narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory, where your jar is and start it with

```
java -jar XBee jar
```

Does it work?

Comment: The program is not an executable. It is a library package that I am using from another program.

Comment: Might you have a copy in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext? (Win-platform: %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext)